# Time requests in NodeJS/Express

Tags: node.js, express

What would be the best way to time all requests coming into my node app? Basically I want to get the current timestamp at the very beginning of the request and then again at the very end of the request, get the difference and log it. Recommendations on the best way to do this in NodeJS and Express?

Here is a sample of what my app looks like (although a lot more complex than this).

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send(200, 'hi');
});

app.get('/about', function(req, res, next) {
   res.send(200, 'something else');
});

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(9000);
console.log("Express server listening...");
```

I want to time ALL requests. So I want to time `/` and `/about` and anything other endpoint I might add.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This might do the trick: http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/responseTime.html

```
app.use(express.responseTime());
```

Or do something like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) { req.start = Date.now(); next(); });

app.get(...);
app.get(...);

app.use(function(req, res) { var time = Date.now() - req.start; });
```

This requires that all your routes call `next()`.

Or maybe this (same thing as responseTime middleware, but doesn't set a header):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var start = Date.now();
    res.on('header', function() {
        var duration = Date.now() - start;
        // log duration
    });
    next();
});
```

> **header** event is fired by Connect middleware in express which is removed as of version 4. Follow this answer for solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27348342/4969957

Instead of listening for the `'header'` event on `res` which fires once the headers are sent, you can listen for the `'finish'` event, depending on what you want to measure.

Comment: This is the only answer that appears to have understood the fundamentals of middleware in express. +1

Comment: This is perfect. I coupled it with Rollbar to report slow routes

Comment: The second option (with 'finish') is the best.

Comment: The approved answer has two issues: 1) I should notice that not every request comes to the “finish” state, in the real life client can close the connection before the response has been sent. In this case Node.js emits only the res.on('close') event. 2) JavaScript Date class (e.g. Date.getTime()) has several disadvantages such as limitation to milliseconds (hard to measure functions executing for a fraction of a millisecond) and a vulnerability to a clock drifts. I wrote a post about measuring requests duration check it out (https://slao.io/blog/posts/request-duration/)

Answer (score 7):

```
export const measureRequestDuration = (req, res, next) => {
const start = Date.now();
res.once('finish', () => {
    const duration = Date.now() - start; 
    console.log("Time taken to process " + req.originalUrl + " is: " + 
  duration);
   });
 next();
};
```

And then

```
app.use(measureRequestDuration);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the built-in [`console.time`](http://nodejs.org/api/stdio.html#stdio_console_time_label) and [`console.timeEnd`](http://nodejs.org/api/stdio.html#stdio_console_timeend_label) functions for this:

```
console.time('handler name');
... handle the request
console.timeEnd('handler name');
```

Output to console:

```
handler name: 62ms
```

Comment: Cool, is this wrappable as node middleware for all routes?

Comment: How can this be applied to a node/express app? Where does this go to wrap all requests?

Comment: It cannot be applied generally, no.

Answer (score 6):

you can add to your middleware the module `morgan` and use it like this-

```
const morgan = require('morgan')
...
...
const app = express()
app.use(morgan('dev'))
```

Then the logs will look like this:

```
// :method :url :status :response-time ms - :res[content-length]
GET /myroute 200 339.051 ms - 242
```

Check [morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan) :)

Answer (score 3):

Or if you want a bigger time resolution you could use [process.hrtime()](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime) or use a module I've build that uses hrtime but gives you a lot of extra info like average, median, total time etc. the module is called [exectimer](https://github.com/alexandrusavin/exectimer). This is an example:

```
var t = require("exectimer");

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var tick = new t.Tick("responseTime");
  tick.start();
  res.on('header', function() {
    tick.stop();
  });
  next();
});

// when ready check the results with this:
var responseTime = t.timers.responseTime;
console.log(responseTime.min()); // minimal response time
console.log(responseTime.max()); // minimal response time
console.log(responseTime.mean()); // mean response time
console.log(responseTime.median()); // median response time
```

It is very accurate and has a resolution of nanoseconds and no extra dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Just get the current time in milliseconds (e.g. via `new Date()`) when you first get a handle on the request and then the time when you finish the response and take the difference as the elapsed time in milliseconds.

```javascript
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.timeStart = new Date();
  // ...
  res.end(...);
  var timeStop = new Date();
  console.log('Elapsed ' + (timeStop-req.timeStart) + 'ms');
});
```

Note that you can subtract dates since `Date#valueOf()` returns their time in milliseconds.

Comment: Wouldn't that only work if I only had one handler? I have dozens of handlers and endpoints.

Comment: @tbeauvais: you could attach the "timeStart" to the response itself, see my updated answer.

Comment: I updated my question with a sample of what my app looks like. Maybe I'm missing something but I still don't see how this would work for multiple endpoints (aside from me adding that bit of a code to every handler which I'm trying to avoid).

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the response-time middleware for express, is the one mentioned by Trevor Dixon on the first answer. It now allows you to set a callback to get hold of the response time, in case you don't need to set the X-Response-Time header on your response. https://github.com/expressjs/response-time#responsetimefn

Comment: When complementing an answer, you can just comment it instead of creating a new answer