# Express res header event no longer firing

Tags: node.js, express

I have a middleware function that was effectively pass-through, but was used for logging response status codes, start time, end time, etc.  At some point this code stopped working, likely after upgrading to Express 4.

```
module.exports = function () {
  var app = express();

  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.on('header', function () {
      // Here I could inspect res.headers, res.statusCode, etc.
      // This 'header' event seems to no longer be fired.
    }

    next();
  });

  return app;
}
```

I have also tried using `express.Router()` instead of `express()`, but there is no difference in behavior.

Is this functionality gone?  Is there an alternative solution to getting the response headers *after* some other middleware has sent a response, but *before* the response body ends?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the `header` event on response objects was fired up Connect.  This event was deprecated in Connect 2.x, and removed as of Connect 3.x.  From the [Connect 2.x source code](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/2.x/lib/patch.js#L143):

```
  res.on = function(type, listener){
    if (type === 'header') {
      deprecate('res.on("header"): use on-headers npm module instead');
      onHeaders(this, listener);
      return this;
    }

    return addListener.apply(this, arguments);
  };
```

The suggested module:  https://www.npmjs.org/package/on-headers

Answer (score 2):

`header` event is fired by `Connect` middleware.

Quoting from ExpressJS Wiki

> **Express 4 no longer has Connect as a dependency.** This means that ALL
>   bundled middleware (except static) is no longer available on the
>   express module. Each middleware is available as a module. (More on
>   this below.)
>
> This change allows middleware to receive fixes, updates, and releases,
>   without impacting Express release cycles (and vice-versa).

Source: https://github.com/strongloop/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x

Comment: Thanks @Sobiaholic.  It turns out that this event was also removed from Connect.  There is a heavily used duck punch that seems to be well tested as an alternative:  https://www.npmjs.org/package/on-headers