# Node express request is ending much later than when res.json is called

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

[node v16.13.1]

I'm trying to debug a node/express server issue where even though I'm calling `res.json(data)`, the client-side network request stays `(Pending)` for much longer after.

Can someone tell me how I can debug or investigate why this is happening on only some requests?

One theory I have is that it is somehow serializing large JSON, but I still wouldn't expect that to take 30+ seconds.

In my server code:

```js
app.post((req, res) => {
  console.time('request');
  //...build response...
  console.timeEnd('request'); // 1.020s

  console.time('res.json');
  res.json(response);
  console.timeEnd('res.json'); // 13.828ms
});
```

The node logs show that `request` only took 1 second:

```
request: 1.230s
res.json: 13.828ms
```

Why would the client-side request show as taking 30 seconds "Waiting for server response"?
[image: Screenshot of client-side request showing 28 seconds]

Comment: Well have you tried putting the `timeEnd` *after* the `res.json()` call?

Comment: What is sitting between the server and the client?

Comment: Are you getting the log immediately (towards the start of the 30s) or late (towards the end)? Put client and server output side by side, for 30s it should be obvious. (For smaller durations you'd need additional instrumentation, but for multiple seconds wall clock time is fine)

Comment: @Bergi yes thanks, just updated (only 13ms before/after). This request is made through a chrome extension but I don't think that's relevant. it works for all requests, except this one payload but I don't see any reason why it would cause such a delay. I can see the 30 seconds happening much later than the `console.timeEnd` which seems expected.

Comment: Do you have any other express  Middleware that is executed before this request? See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538537/time-requests-in-nodejs-express on how to measure the whole duration of your request from the very beginning to the very end with all middlewares included

Comment: Thanks @derpirscher! The plot thickens.. listening for `res.on('finish')` from your link confirms the request is taking ~30 seconds. So now I need to figure out why the "finish" event is so late after I call `res.json`